# Проверка формы на заполненые поля

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

```
function showError(container, errorMessage) {
  container.className = 'error';
  var msgElem = document.createElement('span');
  msgElem.className = "error-message";
  msgElem.innerHTML = errorMessage;
  container.appendChild(msgElem);
}

function resetError(container) {
  container.className = '';
  if (container.lastChild.className == "error-message") {
    container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
  }
}

function validate(form) {
  var elems = form.elements;

  resetError(elems.firstname.parentNode);
  if (!elems.firstname.value) {
    showError(elems.firstname.parentNode, ' Укажите ваше имя.');
  }

  resetError(elems.lastname.parentNode);
  if (!elems.lastname.value) {
    showError(elems.lastname.parentNode, ' Укажите вашу фамилию.');
  }

  resetError(elems.password.parentNode);
  if (!elems.password.value) {
    showError(elems.password.parentNode, ' Укажите пароль.');
  } 

  resetError(elems.email.parentNode);
  if (!elems.email.value) {
    showError(elems.email.parentNode, ' Укажите правильный электронный адрес');
  }

  resetError(elems.address.parentNode);
  if (!elems.address.value) {
    showError(elems.address.parentNode, ' Укажите ваш адрес');
  }

  resetError(elems.datepicker.parentNode);
  if (!elems.datepicker.value) {
    showError(elems.datepicker.parentNode, ' Укажите правильную дату');
  }

  return;

}
```

Есть код

Как сделать проверку полей универсальною: без привязки к количеству полей!
Проверку (если необходима) сделать в зависимосты от типа (type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form>
  <input type="text" class="validated" name="firstname" title="Укажите ваше имя." />
  ..
</form>

var validationFailed = false;
$("form input.validated").each(function(){
  resetError(this.parentNode);
  if (!this.value) {
    showError(this.parentNode, $(this).attr('title'));
    validationFailed = true;
  }
});
```

Comment: если у меня есть еще type="mail" type="number" . type="password" как быть?)

Comment: добавьте им всем `class="validated"` и выбирайте `$("form input.validated")`

Comment: а с ошибкой как поступить?

Comment: @СергійЧуйко С какой ошибкой?

Comment: уже розобрался) вы сможете помочь еще с вот этим вопросом)
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/834488/%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC

Comment: @СергійЧуйко Обратите внимание на значок "галочка" слева от ответа.