# Валидация формы со всплывающим окном

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-form

```js
function showError(container, errorMessage) {
  container.className = 'error';
  var msgElem = document.createElement('span');
  msgElem.className = "error-message";
  msgElem.innerHTML = errorMessage;
  container.appendChild(msgElem);
}

function resetError(container) {
  container.className = '';
  if (container.lastChild.className == "error-message") {
    container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
  }
}

function validate(form) {
  var validationFailed = false;
  $(".valid-from input").each(function() {
    resetError(this.parentNode);
    if (!this.value) {
      showError(this.parentNode, $(this).attr('title'));
      validationFailed = true;
    }
  });
}

// Код всплывающего окна

document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  validate(this);
  if (document.getElementsByClassName('error-message').length > 0) {
    return;
  } else {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" name="registration" id="myForm">
  <div class="valid-from">
    <label for="firstname">Имя</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" title="Укажите ваше имя" placeholder="John" />
  </div>
  <div class="valid-from">
    <label for="lastname">Фамилия</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" title="Укажите вашу фамилию" placeholder="Doe" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Как изменить логику модалки что бы тригером был результат функции validate?

Comment: Переформулируйте вопрос.

Comment: а что не так с вопросом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function validate(form) {
  var validationFailed = false;
  ...
  return !validationFailed;
}

// Код всплывающего окна

document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (validate(this)) {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
  }
});
```

Comment: спасибо вам большое)

а с этим вопросом можете помочь?)
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/834123/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8-required

Comment: @СергійЧуйко Когда приду с собрания ).

Comment: буду ждать вас))

Comment: @СергійЧуйко Но Вы пока сами попытайтесь. Здесь косо смотрят на однострочные вопросы без попыток самостоятельного решения.

Comment: я уже все перепробовал) могу прикрепить код) который делаю)

Comment: и если вас не затруднит) глянуть еще вот это)
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/834614/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B 

@Igor